# Validator not validate hidden input field Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, validation, input, laravel-livewire, hidden-field

I'm passing a date from livewire function to the modal and put it in input field like this:

```html
<input wire:model.defer="state.schedule_date" value="{{$startDate}}" type="hidden">
```

Then, the form submit to livewire function.

```php
public function addScheduleRoute()
{
    $out = new ConsoleOutput();
    $out->writeln("YOU ARE IN HERE");

    $validatedData = Validator::make($this->state, [
        'schedule_date' => ['required'],
        'sequence'=> ['required', 'int']])->validate();

    RouteSchedule::create($validatedData);
}
```

There's 'YOU ARE IN HERE' output means it's going to the right function but I'm stuck at the form page like I'm clicked the add button and nothing happened. The DB is not updated.

When I remove `schedule_date` from the validator, it's working. Idk what is wrong, I checked that `$startDate` is not null, it has value tho

Answer (score -1):

Try to change :

```
<input wire:model.defer="state.schedule_date" value="{{$startDate}}" type="hidden">
```

To this :

```
<input wire:model.defer="state.schedule_date" value="{{$startDate}}" type="text" hidden>
```